# How to handle connection reset by client from tomcat 8

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, connection

I have a simple webbapp deployed in tomcat8. But some HTTP requests requires access to DB with slow queries. Sometimes HTTP client made reset connection. In the same time i'd like to handle it in my webapp for cancel slow query (which result is no longer interesting).

The main question: "How to catch reset connection from client side in phase awaiting response from server". Is it possible? Interrupting thread - the best way for it because I can easly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

When connection is broken from client side tomcat does not interrupts http-nio-X thread. Why? How to do it?